# How to improve performance for LDA?

Tags: python, topic-models, word-embeddings, latent-dirichlet-alloc, tf-idf

I am running LDA on health-related data. Specifically I have ~500 documents that contain interviews that last around 5-7 pages. Other than that, I cannot really go into the details of the data due to preserving data integrity/confidentiality. Although I unfortunately cannot show the results output, I will describe the results and then go through my procedure to give a better idea of what I am doing and where I can improve.

For the results, I chose 20 topics and outputted 10 words per topic. Although 20 was somewhat arbitrary and I did not have a clear idea of a good amount of topics, that seemed like a good amount given the size of the data and that they are all health-specific. However, the results highlighted two issues: 1) it is unclear what the topics were since the words within each topic did not necessarily go together or tell a story and 2) many of the words among the various topics overlapped, and there were a few words that showed up in most topics.

In terms of what I did, I first preprocessed the text. I converted everything to lowercase, removed punctuation, removed unnecessary codings specific to the set of documents at hand. I then tokenized the documents, lemmatized the words, and performed tf-idf. I used sklearn's tf-idf capabilities and within tf-idf initialization, I specified a customized list of stopwords to be removed (which added to nltk's set of stopwords). I also set max_df to 0.9 (unclear what a good number is, I just played around with different values), min_df to 2, and max_features to 5000. I tried both tf-idf and bag of words (count vectorizer), but I found tf-idf to give slightly clearer and more distinct topics while analyzing the LDA output. After this was done, I then ran an LDA model. I set the number of topics to be 20 and the number of iterations to 5.

From my understanding, each decision I made above may have contributed to the LDA model's ability to identify clear, meaningful topics. I know that text processing plays a huge role in LDA performance, and the better job I do there, the more insightful the LDA will be. Is there anything glaringly wrong or something I missed out. Do you have any suggested values/explorations for any of the parameters I described above? How do I determine a good number of topics and iterations during the LDA step? How do I go about validating performance, other than qualitatively comparing output?

I appreciate any advice or suggestions that you have! I am completely new to the area of topic modeling and while I have read some articles, I have a lot to learn! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your preprocessing steps are fine, there isn't too much you can do there.

I think that 5 iterations is way too small because LDA usually takes a really long time to converge, even when using the Variational Bayes algorithm. Whenever I use LDA, I give it at least a 100 iterations. Another suggestion is to keep track of how the LDA model's perplexity changes over time while training, and decide on the number of iterations accordingly.

I would also suggest trying to not reduce the number of dimensions to 5000, depending on the use case, it may or may not be a good idea. You can try running LDA without any dimensionality reduction on the vectorizer, and see what you get.

Be careful about the max_df and min_df parameters in sklearn's TfidfVectorizer. When you use a float between 0 and 1, it corresponds to the fraction of documents. When you use an integer, it corresponds to the absolute count of documents.